# getting error while configure two websites on different port no of same ip?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I tried to configure virtual host in apache configuration file . my requirement is host two sites in same ip but different ports.

```
Listen 192.168.2.10:80
Listen 192.168.2.10:9021

NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.10:80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.10:9021

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.10:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/white-socks
   ServerName www.white-socks.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.10:9021>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/black-socks
    ServerName www.black-socks.com
</VirtualHost>
```

That is my configuration in "httpd.conf".
But i am getting  error like below

```
[root@ram conf]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ram
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain    name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address  192.168.2.10:9021
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                       [FAILED]
[root@ram conf]#
```

What is my mistake and what i have to do to solve this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please ask questions about server configuration on ServerFault. Please read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about what's on topic and what's not. Link is always at the top of each page.

Comment: Try removing IP address from `<virtualhost *:80>` directive. You already specified `Listen` address. And add IP details in your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: i am getting this error if we use * instead of ip address.

'Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ram
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[warn] NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.10:80 has no VirtualHosts
[warn] NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.10:2233 has no VirtualHosts
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 192.168.2.10:2233
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                               [FAILED]'

Comment: already added in /etc/host file also .